# How to convert JSON data to HTML page as under each date show category + time1?

Tags: javascript

I have this JSON data

```
myArray = [
  { 'category': 'apple', 'date': '20/4/2023', 'time1': '12:30' },
  { 'category': 'banana', 'date': '20/4/2023', 'time1': '12:32' },
  { 'category': 'tv', 'date': '21/4/2023', 'time1': '12:34' },
  { 'category': 'banana', 'date': '21/4/2023', 'time1': '12:39' },

];
```

I want to show this data on a HTML page as line of date and under each date all related category to that date + time1.

Expected output can be as:

```
----------20/4/2023-------------
apple 12:30
banana 12:32
----------21/4/2023-------------
tv 12:34
banana 12:39
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var groupedArray = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.date] = acc[curr.date] || 0;
  acc[curr.date]++;
  return acc;
}, {});

for (var date in groupedArray) {
  console.log(`${date}: ${groupedArray[date]}`);
}
```

This will give you the output as count by date.

Comment: I edited the question, I want to see date on html page as h1 & categories as h4 according to myArray